# "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

So I have the following task - I need to deserialize an array of Jason objects which is stored in a recourse folder in my application.

So far I have accessed the recourse and stored it into a var:

`var jsonData = Resources.SamplePoints;`

Converted the array into a string:

`string jsonObjts = Encoding.Default.GetString(jsonData);`

And have tried to write the result into a list of Dictionaries

`List<Dictionary<string, double>> EntityData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, double>>>(jsonObjts);`

However the above error message shows up when I run and test the application.

Can anyone please set me on the right path how to fix this?

A sample of the objects in question:

```
"samples": [
{
    "date": "2014-08-10T09:00:00Z",
    "temperature": 10,
    "pH": 4,
    "phosphate": 4,
    "chloride": 4,
    "nitrate": 10
},
{
    "date": "2014-08-12T09:05:00Z",
    "temperature": 10.5,
    "pH": 5,
    "chloride": 4,
    "phosphate": 4
},
```

Comment: Make sure your `Deserialization` object has a property named as `samples` which is of an `IEnumerable` type. Or it would be better you could post the object used for `deserialization`.

Comment: Possible, "date": "2014-08-12T09:05:00Z"  is a problem. Try List<Dictionary<string, object>> or List<Dictionary<string, string>> and reparse numbers by double.Parse.

Comment: And read this before JSON.NET usage https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm

Comment: You can generate C# object based on JSON response from here http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't want to create a class to represent your JSON?

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public List<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
}

public class Sample
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public float Temperature { get; set; }
    public int Ph { get; set; }
    public int Phosphate { get; set; }
    public int Chloride { get; set; }
    public int Nitrate { get; set; }
}
```

then you can deserialize:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

If you still want to use a Dictionary, I think you need something like this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you this works in both cases. I will use a class to represent my Jason objects

Answer (score 0):

Your schema in generic type `List<Dictionary<string, double>>` and schema of json does not match. If you want to cast to `List<Dictionary` you can't use `"samples": [` For this you'll need `Dictionary<string,List<Dictionary`.
Also when you are trying to use `double`, date won't get parsed to double. So maybe you can try `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, object>>>`. Ideally you should create class for this structure instead of using generic List, Dictionary structure.If you are using visual studio, you can create these classes by using Edit->Paste special-> paste json as classes